# How can one earn some Bitcoins with minimal skill requirements?

Tags: job, earnings

This issue came up during a chat on [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4910/323) to a question asked by a new Bitcoin user.

Lets say I am new to Bitcoin and don't want to go through the hassle of exchanging money for coins quite yet. I don't have much of marketable skills, so I can't offer my services. How then can I earn some Bitcoins with minimal skill requirements, without any long-term commitment or investment of any type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most popular way to earn a bit of Bitcoins without any much skill is [mining](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining). The amount of coins one could earn is pretty small even with higher-end graphic cards, but through the use of mining pools and alt-coin mining one could get a small start in the Bitcoin world.

A website that offers small Bitcoin rewards for mechanical-turk-esque small tasks is [CoinWorker](http://coinworker.com/). The skill requirement is minimal and the service provides value to people paying for the task.

Comment: Linked CoinWorker website is still up (and STILL Beta Test!).

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin community is relatively tiny yet.  While there are some tasks here and there where bitcoins can be earned (e.g., logo creation, tutor), there is a far larger number of individuals willing to compete for the work.

Offering to sell bitcoins to others is one way to earn a little.  There are many people who sell coins through LocalBitcoins and earn a few percent on each trade.

- http://www.LocalBitcoins.com

But other than that, if your aim is to acquire some coins the likely more productive avenue would be to find income elsewhere and use that cash to buy bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to invest something (time, money, skill, energy) but there certainly are ways to earn bitcoin without any real monetary investment.

Here are the 3 sites I've used to get all the info I need for this exact question...

http://www.gr1innovations.com/how-to-make-money-with-bitcoin.html

http://earn-bitcoins.com

https://99bitcoins.com/how-to-earn-bitcoins-fast-free/

A lot of the tips are the same/similar on each one, but it's definitely some great ideas for earning bitcoins.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried mining but found out that the electricity used by your pc cost you more then the bitcoins you can get this way,so it is not  worth it unless you invest in some very specific hardware and have the patience and time to see your bath tub get filled a drop at the time

Comment: please don't do bitcoin mining at home pc because the profit obtained will be less than what you have spent for the power bill.